# Same and Duplicate style in sidebar and footer

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, sidebar

i change my footer style in my cross-apple wordpress theme, 
and i notice that the footer was duplicate the style from the sidebar category style.

see here the sidebar style that work good:
http://cor.co.il/contact

also, i have notice that my other sidebar was changed to the footer style. 
see here the sidebar at the right:
http://cor.co.il/video

now, i was div into the style code and tried to change some things but without success.

here is my site: http://cor.co.il

how can i change the footer style to work as different style (the style that display at my [homepage](http://cor.co.il)), and the sidebar to work as different style (the style at my [contact page](http://cor.co.il/contact))?

here is the css files:

[layout.css](http://cor.co.il/wp-content/themes/cross-apple/assets/css/layout.css)

[widgets.css](http://cor.co.il/wp-content/themes/cross-apple/assets/css/widgets.css)

and the gray style:

[style-grey.css](http://cor.co.il/wp-content/themes/cross-apple/assets/css/styles/style-grey.css)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us how you modified the footer style? By editing style.css for that theme or some other way ? A quick inspect element shows that your footer widget is getting a class called widget_nav and your sidebar is getting a widget_categories which should be the other way round.

Comment: i was add the css files addresses

Answer (score 0):

Solved (again) in myself!

in the widgets.css i add the #sidebar before any widget i want him to display on the side bar.
so, it look like this:

```
#sidbar .widget_categories h3
#sidbar .widget_categories li
(padding: 8px 0;)
```

instead of:

```
.widget_categories h3
.widget_categories li
(padding: 8px 0;)
```

and it work!